Powering BLDC motor with 20V 2.5A battery
I have a Pichler Boost 20 motor. Max power load is at 25A/30s, recommended batteries are LiPo 7V or 11V. However, I'm generally against using LiPo batteries. I have however multiple batteries available from cordless drills as well as plenty of rechargeable 8000mAh NiMH batteries.
The motor will be part of a ball shooter mechanism it will be under load for very short period of times, under 1s other times it will just spin freely. To the motor will be attached a rubber wheel @ 40g and 45mm diameter. So not a lot of load and the load won't be constant.
I already tested running the BLDC motors with both Lithium-Ion and NiMH batteries and it works flawlessly with both with NiMH I can stay at the recommended voltage. Mainly what I want to know is the implications of using the 20V 2.5A Lithium-Ion cordless drill battery (of which I don't know the C rating seems impossible to find out).
I let the motors run at full speed for a while and checked the temperature of both and neither seems to be increasing (tho I didn't test under load). What are the implications here and considerations I need to make.
Additionally say I power the motors with 20V but don't allow them to be maxed by software, out since 50% of the power/speed is more than enough.
